# Quick Edit not available for contributors?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, office-365

I have a document library that has broken permissions. In my document library are folders, and in addition to the site groups having access to all the folders, individuals are granted contribute access on a per folder basis.

Site owners and members can interact with the file metadata using the "Quick Edit" functionality, but quick edit is disabled for the contributors. I don't see a permission level setting to enable it for them, and the editable grid is otherwise set in the library settings. Does anyone know how I might enable this for the contributors?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: What is the permission granted for the users to the document library? "The users" means that who have contribute permissions for a certain folder.

Comment: @EmilyDu-MSFT the users have Limited Access to the document library and Contribute on the folders. I can't give them blanket permissions on the document library or else they would be able to see all folders, correct?